# How to convert local coordinates to UTM/WGS84

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, cad

We have received 500 + CAD drawings which refers to local custom coordinate system.
We have seen the grid values in some of the CAD drawings as
N.3052.100 E.1496.600
N.3007.100 E.1551.600

Geodetic parameters given as below. Is there any way to convert local coordinate system to UTM or WGS84?

[image: Geodetic INFORMATION]

Comment: I don't think you have enough information to transform your local coordinates to UTM39. Can you post a few of those CAD drawings?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: Use project https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm

Comment: I am using both softwares.